# Serialize a class that contains a list?

Tags: c#, list, serialization

I may be doing this all wrong here, but I created a class that contains a list and I need to serialize that list.  (Is there a better way or other suggestions to have multiple interfaces without a list?)

I've been doing okay with serializing custom classes, but this one for some reason isn't working out.

```
[XmlRoot("interfaces", Namespace = "")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Interface))]
public class Interfaces
{
    [XmlArray("interfaces")]
    [XmlArrayItem("interface")]
    List<Interface> _IflList = new List<Interface>();
    public List<Interface> IflList
    {
        get { return _IflList; }
        set { _IflList = value; }
    }
    public void Add(Interface objInterface)
    {
        _IflList.Add(objInterface);
    }
}

[XmlType("interface")]
public class Interface
{
    string _name;
    public string name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
    public Interface(string name)
    {
        this._name = name;
    }
}
```

I get the error `There was an error reflecting type 'JunOSConfig.Interfaces'` when trying to serialize with:

```
    public string SerializeObject(object objToSerialize, bool StripXmlVer, bool FormatOutput)
    {
        string strReturn = "";

        XmlSerializerNamespaces xns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        xns.Add("", "");
        Type objType = typeof(JunOSConfig.Interfaces);
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(objToSerialize.GetType());
        XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
        xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = StripXmlVer;

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw, xws);

        xs.Serialize(xw, objToSerialize, xns);
        strReturn = sw.ToString();

        if (FormatOutput)
        {
            return Convert.ToString(XElement.Parse(strReturn));
        }
        else
        {
            return strReturn;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You will need a parameterless constructor

Comment: In general, when you post exceptions, you should post all inner exceptions as well (use ex.ToString()). This is especially true for exceptions from the XML Serializer. The inner exceptions quite likely tell you exactly what's wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Isn't Imterface a protected keyword?

Comment: Consider renaming Interface(s) to something else since c# has an interface keyword already.  It is confusing...

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I change the Interface to JunosInterface.  I've also found that adding the constructor of `public JunosInterface(string name)` is breaking it.  If I leave that out, it works.  Any ideas?

Comment: I would keep the constructor that doesn't require an argument and change the other (constructor that reqires an argument) into a factory method (static function that takes an argument, makes an instance of this, populates it and returns it)

Comment: tgolisch, can you provide an example?  Kinda new to C#

Comment: Actually I worked it out by adding `public Junosinterface(){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to your constructor with one parameter

```
public Interface(string name)
{
    this._name = name;
}
```

you will need another, parameterless constructor, like

```
public Interface()
{
}
```

If you do not declare a constructor yourself, a constructor without
parameters will be generated.

Then it should work.